# pendingDynamicLinkData shows null

Tags: android, dynamic-linking

I am developing an app which can share and been reward so I use the concept of the dynamic link so to store the information of inviter in that link and later be rewarded. but the PendingDynamicLinkData return null on installing the app after reffered.

MainActivity

```
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        Log.d("successpra", "onSuccess: ");
                        String referrerUid = deepLink.getQueryParameter("invitedby");
                        Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,referrerUid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"referrerUid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

onclick button of share and earn

```
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        Log.d("prashu",uid);
        String link = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XUPfiBGCSydmgwEE7E-IRatAeGVuMbOr&?invitedby="+uid;
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
                .setDynamicLinkDomain("nw8y9.app.goo.gl")
                .setAndroidParameters(
                        new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.example.android")
                                .setMinimumVersion(125)
                                .build())
                .setIosParameters(
                        new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.example.ios")
                                .setAppStoreId("123456789")
                                .setMinimumVersion("1.0.1")
                                .build())
                .buildShortDynamicLink()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink) {
                        Uri mInvitationUrl = shortDynamicLink.getShortLink();
                        Log.d("prashu",mInvitationUrl.toString());
                        String referrerName =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                        String subject = String.format("%s wants you to play MyExampleGame!", referrerName);
                        String invitationLink = mInvitationUrl.toString();
                        String msg = "Let's play MyExampleGame together! Use my referrer link: "
                                + invitationLink;
                        String msgHtml = String.format("<p>Let's play MyExampleGame together! Use my "
                                + "<a href=\"%s\">referrer link</a>!</p>", invitationLink);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setType("text/plain");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, msgHtml);
                        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="drive.google.com/open?id=1xupfibgcsydmgwee7e-irataegvumbor" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="drive.google.com/open?id=1xupfibgcsydmgwee7e-irataegvumbor" android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

thank u in advance, ur help is appreciable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possbile causes:

**1. Incorrect package name**

Are you sure your app's package name is `com.example.android` as
    mentioned

in `new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.example.android")`

The required package name over here is your `applicationId` in the app level `build.gradle` file.

**2. Incorrect URL formation due to** `DynamicLinkDomain`

My URL wasn't correct as it turned out to be `https://app_code.app.goo.gl?.....` 
I had to change the `domain` to `app_code.app.goo.gl/` (forward slash appended at the end now) and only then it became a valid URL.

**3. Incorrect URL formation due to encoded URL**

Performing `String invitationLink = mInvitationUrl.toString();` would convert your deep link i.e. `"https://drive.google.com/open?....."` to change to `"https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.goo...."`. For that you'd need to use the `URLDecoder.decode(mInvitationUrl.toString(), "UTF-8");` method. This would return a `String` that would the same as the valid URL required.

**Tip:**

You don't need to provide the complete url under `android:host=""` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Just `android:host="drive.google.com"` would do as that would allow your app to open all `drive.google.com` URLs.